# Text alignment in sending mail

Tags: asp.net, email, alignment

I am learning ASP.Net from Wrox Beginners ASP.Net 4.0. Here, I am sending a mail from my website to my mail. For that, I created a Text file in App_Data folder and wrote some Content like:

```
Name:          ##Name##
E-mail address:##Email##
Comments:      ##Body##
```

While submitting the form I replaced these contents with following respective content:

```
string filename = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ContactForm.txt");
string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(filename);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Name##", Name.Text);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Email##", EmailAddress.Text);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Comments##", Comments.Text);
```

and sent the mailBody to my mail. My output in the mail was like:

```
Name:                           Andrew Thomas
E-mail address:         andrew@voxcode.com
Comments:                       Its a great Site. But would like to see more of Spanish songs.
```

Why my Contents are not aligned as in the template text file. I have lot of fields apart from name, email and comments. And all are highly un-aligned. What should I do to make them align before sending them to my mail. I was expecting my mail as:

```
Name:                   Andrew Thomas
E-mail address:         andrew@voxcode.com
Comments:               Its a great Site. But would like to see more of Spanish songs.
```

I am no sure if CSS could help here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want perfect alignment, I recommend that you use tables in your message as so:

```
<table border="0">
<tr>
<td>
Name:</td><td>##Name##</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
E-mail address:</td></td>##Email##</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
Comments:</td><td>##Comments##</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Example:

```
MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();

string filename = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ContactForm.txt");
string mailBody = File.ReadAllText(filename);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Name##", Name.Text);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Email##", EmailAddress.Text);
mailBody = mailBody.Replace("##Comments##", Comments.Text);
mm.Body=mailBody;
mm.IsBodyHtml=true;
```

Comment: I am using Text file in App_Data. How can I use tables there??

Comment: It doesn't matter if a text file. You can enter HTML code in text files and make sure you set the `IsHtml` property of the email body  to `true`

Comment: but I believe it will increase the file size a lot....to be sent through mail. and do you mean `IsBodyHtml` of email body

Comment: @rapsalands I just posted an example.

Comment: @rapsalands No, it won't increase the file size a lot. Yes, I meant `IsBodyHtml`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your template contains tabs and that when you read it in they are being converted to spaces. Check the original file only contains spaces or tabs.

Comment: OK, it's because the line that says 'Email:' in your template has changed to 'Email address:' in your output and your tabs are not aligning any more. You need to sort that out

Comment: I tried to replace tabs with spaces, its not working. I tries replacing Email to Email Address, its still not working.